# setInterval is it the correct way to get notifications?

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications, yii2-advanced-app

i need to create a messages notifications in my system built by yii2 ,

so i used this way

1- i created in messages Controller function getnew :

```
public function actionGetnew()  
{
     $query1 = new Query;                              
      $query1->select([" count(*) as  price "]   )
              ->from('messeges');
              //->where // here   i will add the id of user that logged in and the state of unread messages ! 
     $command1 = $query1->createCommand();
     $price = $command1->queryAll();  
     echo Json::encode($price); 
}
```

2- i created a js file  :

```
window.onload = function() {

   setInterval(function(){ 
    $.get('index.php?r=messeges/getnew',function(data)
    {
        var data=$.parseJSON(data);

        $(".messages").html(data[0].price);
    });
 }, 5000);
};
```

3- i added HTML tag like this :

```
  <h6 class="messages"></h6>
```

everything work fine but my question is that right way to do it ? ,  is that will add more traffic and load  on my server ?   if there is a better idea please notify me  !

Comment: Explore socket.io. It is used to build real time data streaming kind of application, which also include notification systems

Answer (score 1):

It isn't best way to do this.

You are right - it could cause traffic and load increase.

Better options are:

1. [Longpooling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/)
2. [Server events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)
3. [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

First of all try to consider [socket.io](https://socket.io/) (they have some problems with website - try to go on it later :-) )